# Postgres 11.9: Query is searching all partitions for partition by tstzrange

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have partitioned a table based on column of type tstzrange

```
CREATE TABLE schedule_slots
(
    id                     int8        NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('schedule_slots_id_seq'::regclass),
    time_range             tstzrange   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT schedule_slots_pkey2 PRIMARY KEY (id, time_range)
) partition by range(time_range);

CREATE
INDEX time_range_idx2 ON schedule_slots USING gist (time_range);
```

Created below partitions :

```
CREATE TABLE schedule_slots_part1 PARTITION OF schedule_slots
    FOR VALUES FROM ('[2022-06-01 00:00:00-07,2022-06-01 23:59:59-07)') to ('[2022-09-01 00:00:00-07,2022-09-01 23:59:59-07)');

CREATE TABLE schedule_slots_part2 PARTITION OF schedule_slots
    FOR VALUES FROM ('[2022-09-01 00:00:00-07,2022-09-01 23:59:59-07)') to ('[2022-12-01 00:00:00-07,2022-12-01 23:59:59-07)');   

CREATE TABLE schedule_slots_part3 PARTITION OF schedule_slots
    FOR VALUES FROM ('[2022-12-01 00:00:00-07,2022-12-01 23:59:59-07)') to ('[2023-02-01 00:00:00-07,2023-02-01 23:59:59-07)');    

CREATE TABLE schedule_slots_part4 PARTITION OF schedule_slots
    FOR VALUES FROM ('[2023-02-01 00:00:00-07,2023-02-01 23:59:59-07)') to ('[2023-05-01 00:00:00-07,2023-05-01 23:59:59-07)'); 
   

 CREATE TABLE schedule_slots_part5 PARTITION OF schedule_slots
    FOR VALUES FROM ('[2023-05-01 00:00:00-07,2023-05-01 23:59:59-07)') to ('[2023-08-01 00:00:00-07,2023-08-01 23:59:59-07)'); 

    CREATE TABLE schedule_slots_part6 PARTITION OF schedule_slots
    FOR VALUES FROM ('[2023-08-01 00:00:00-07,2023-08-01 23:59:59-07)') to ('[2023-11-01 00:00:00-07,2023-11-01 23:59:59-07)');
```

But below query is searching all partitions instead of only the partition which is suppose to contain this data

```
  select id, time_range  from schedule_slots where  time_range <@ tstzrange('2022-12-01 00:00:00-07','2023-02-01 23:59:59-07', '[]')  ;
```

[image]

I have tried

```
SET enable_partition_pruning = on;

I have updated the db parameter  constraint_exclusion to on
```

but still no luck. Please let me know what am I missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can partition by range on a range datatype. The ranges of ranges that you assigned to your partitions don't really make sense to me either.

Comment: seems not each to understand. the test code (https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/test/regress/expected/partition_prune.out;h=bde29e38a94362ca820f16dc9d84e82127b45572;hb=676887a3b0b8e3c0348ac3f82ab0d16e9a24bd43#l3361)  have some example using range, but partition by range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning and partition pruning don't support GiST operator classes. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) says:

> Range and list partitioning require a btree operator class, while hash partitioning requires a hash operator class. If no operator class is specified explicitly, the default operator class of the appropriate type will be used; if no default operator class exists, an error will be raised.

So there is no chance to get partition pruning in the way you want.

I think that your partitioning strategy is questionable. If your reason for partitioning is to achieve partition pruning, you have a problem.  The only way you might get somewhat effective partition pruning is with an additional condition:

```
select id, time_range
from schedule_slots
where time_range <@ tstzrange('2022-12-01 00:00:00-07','2023-02-01 23:59:59-07', '[]')
  and time_range > tstzrange('2022-12-01 00:00:00-07','2023-02-01 23:59:59-07', '[]');
```

The additional condition should not change the query result, but allow partition pruning. In this example, that will not be effective.

Comment: Thank you so much ! New proposed query is not resulting in the same result. For now, I would be using start_time   timestamptz and end_time  timestamptz  instead of time_range. Would be creating partition based on the start_time.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I used `<` rather than `>`. Perhaps that will make a difference.

Comment: Thanks . It returning same rows now but its searching 4 partitions instead of 1.

Comment: That is as good as it gets.